# SWV Exception Trace is not working in Atollic Studio

Tags: stm32, cubemx, stm32cubemx

I want to trace exceptions/interrupts happening in my board with STM32L4xx in Atollic Studio by  `SWV Exception Trace Log` and `SWV Trace Log`.
I use SEGGER J-Link and In `Debugger` I have correctly set the interface to SWD and the Core Clock to 80 MHz. Also in the Serial Wire Viewer setting, I set the `EXETRC` and `Enable Prescaler`. By pressing `Start Trace`, I get the following **verification error** in console:

```
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE000EDFC - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0042004 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE00400F0 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0040010 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0000FB0 - Verify failed
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0000E80 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0000E40 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0000E00 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0001020 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0001030 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0001040 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0001050 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0001060 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0001000 - Verify failed
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0xE0040304 - Verify failed
```

Do you know what could be possible problems?

Comment: probably Atollic eclipse plugin does not support STM32Lxxx

Comment: How can I confirm that? Can you please explain more

Comment: set the debug registers yourself in the  code

Comment: I could confirm that Atollic Studio is supporting STM32L4xx, and the registers are there. I want to use SWV Exception Trace log to see the interrupts which happen.

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean, so now how can set those register in my code?